# Question about returning a value at the end of a recursive call

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, return-value

In the function *fp*, I am basically checking whether the difference between arguments of succesive recursive calls is less than a certain number and if it is so, I would like to return the last argument. Here is the code:

```
pX = []
for n in range(100):
    pX.append(1/((n+1)*(n+2)))

def phi1(p):
    def phi2(u):
        sum = 0
        for k in range(len(p)):
            sum += p[k]*(u**k)
        return sum
    return phi2

def fp(pt):
    temp = phi1(pX)(pt)
    print(temp)
    if(abs(pt-temp) > 0.01): 
        fp(temp)
    else:
        return temp

print(fp(0.1))
```

The output, without *print(temp)* is none, with *print(temp)* is:

```
0.5175535907956329
0.619369692490415
0.6561427816319753
0.6714277125785142
0.6781654579021761
None
```

Desired output is *0.678*. May I know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't returning anything when your function recurses. Add a `return` to where `fp` is called inside `fp`:

```
def fp(pt):
    temp = phi1(pX)(pt)
    print(temp)
    if(abs(pt-temp) > 0.01): 
        return fp(temp)
    else:
        return temp
```